# A variation of the axiom of choice

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I found an unfamiliar form of AC in the proof of Zorn's lemma in ZFC by [Lewin (1991)](https://digitalcommons.kennesaw.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2161&context=facpubs). I don't even know whether it is natural or not.

$ (X, \le) $ is a poset. In the 5th paragraph of the paper, he introduced ($\exists$ elimination) a choice function $f$ from the family of chains of $X$ to $X$ such that for every chain $C$, $ f(C) $ is a strict upper bound of $C$.

[image]

But it seems that is not a direct application of AC in a usual form as presented in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice#Statement) because $f(C) \notin C$ for every chain $C$.

How is it justified?

Comment: I called $f$ a choice function but it is not adequate because $f$ is the composition of an index function and a choice function according to [Karagila](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4331225/334795) The value of the index function is always nonempty exists because we assumed that $X$ has no maximal member.

Comment: Please don't rely on pictures of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite a natural way of thinking about the axiom of choice. If $C$ is a chain, let $U(C)$ denote the strict upper bounds of $C$. Then the choice function is from $\{U(C)\mid C\subseteq X\text{ is a chain}\}$.

By composing the indexing function, mapping $C$ to $U(C)$ with the chain function, we can think of this as a function assigning each chain a strict upper bound.

Comment: Aside from the original question, the indexing need not be injective?

Comment: No reason for it to be injective. Note that two distinct chains can easily have the same set of strict upper bounds.